# How to hide MySQL generated ID in URL

Tags: php, mysql

Right now I can get the information for a product in my database by simply using its ID in the URL lik so: `http://www.example.com/?productID=5`
Now I can guess the next one since these IDs are all auto incremented.
How would you hide this ID and replace it with something better? I mean it still has to be a unique identifier.
To complicate it a little I was thinking I could use a global unique identifier and add this in the database in another column. But I have the feeling that this is not the best way to do this :)
Please let me know your thoughts and tell me how you solved/would solve this in your project.

**What I basically want is to get rid of knowing the next/previous ID.**

There are no security limitations on the products themselves. Users are most likely allowed to see them. I was thinking that this technique could prevent *crawling* all products?!?

**Like what amazon.com does: It looks like they hide the item's ID in some way, right?**

Comment: Adding a second column with a global random ID is the best way to do it; however, using the raw ID shouldn't be a problem either - if users aren't supposed to access something, you need to actively lock them out; relying on their not being able to guess the URL isn't enough.

Comment: using a GUID isn't a bad idea at all..

Comment: There are lots of cryptographic algorithms which are useful; I do it by calculating the modulus of the ID wrt a (very) large prime number - this meets the criteria that an ID will never be repeated and that each ID is very different to the previous one

Comment: even a very simple `sha1($salt . $id)` would "hide" the values and make them unpredictable.

Comment: The best approach could depend on what underlying business purpose is served by frustrating the user's hacking of URLs as  illustrated.

Comment: Amazon uses its own product number. i.e. /product/B008GGCAVM
I would assume they have a schema for such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a slug which works great for SEO. so Product 1 slug could be http://www.example.com/?productSlug=exampleitemnameasoneword
You just have to make sure slugs are unique. You would of course need a slug field in your database entry and be able to enter/edit it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, have a look at [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

I am making use of `CakePhp`, this allows me to have easy access to urls created by the `.htaccess` rules. In my case, my titles are 100% unique, which allows me to have a slug version of the title.

For example my title is `SZD-51 Junior`, this will become `SZD-51_Junior`. I just add this `slug` to my database and use this as a secondary unique identifier. When a user visits `www.example.com/planes/SZD-51_Junior` I can do something like:

```
// pseudo mysql
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE slug = url_param

//in cakephp
$this->Plane->findBySlug($this->params['slug']);
```

There are a lot of approaches, what would you like the url to become? Which format?

Answer (score 1):

you can use some kind of hashing algorithm like md5(), sha1() etc... and yes, it is better to store that hash in another column in your table for faster lookup.

If you use md5() it is a good practice to seed it with fixed or random salt string.
My favorite is to do it with microtime().

Generate hash before db insert:

```
$salt = "my_secret_salt_string";
$entry['hash_code'] = md5($salt . microtime()); // every time a different result is generated which will ensure uniqueness
// insert into ...
```

Or if you prefer using generated id as a salt, then update entry:

```
// insert into ...
// get id
$entry['hash_code'] = md5($id . microtime());
// update ...
```

Answer (score -2):

A solution to this is to use post instead, this is just a quick mashup i did.

```
<?php

//how to handle the request
if(isset($_POST['transfer']) && !empty($_POST['transfer']))
{
    $transfer = $_POST['transfer'];

    //what to do?
}

?>

//how to make a link with id 5
<a href="javascript:transfer('5');">link</a>

//this is for the functionality
<form id="transfer_form" action="http://www.example.com/" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="transfer" name="productID" value="" />
</form>

//this should be placed within the <head>
<script>
function tranfer(link)
{
    document.getElementById('transfer').value = link;
    document.getElementById('transfer_form').submit();
}
</script>
```

Comment: If you have a website where `results.php` shows results (where I might have `results.php?id=10`), how will I link to your results page for a specific ID?

Comment: No offence but... only newbies think that POST data is secret.

Comment: Well, it's not secret the thing was that it shouldn't show in the addressbar.